# Show modal if user is logged Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code:

```
@auth
   <script>$('#modalLogged').modal('show');</script>
@endauth
```

I need when user close modal, hide this modal in this session. And if user logout and now login, then now show this modal. How I can do it?

Comment: Try setting a cookie

Comment: If you just want to pop up a modal when the user just logged in, then you can use Jquery $(document).ready(function(){ //pop your modal here }

Comment: Also, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your **Logout()** method add below code :

```
 session(['is_model_open' => true]);
```

When Again that user is logged in, get all sessions of users and if `is_model_open == true` then open model

**Note  : default value for `is_model_open` should be `false`**

Comment: Where I need set default value of is_modal_open?

Comment: into your session